# MIDI Java generates messed sound

Tags: java, audio, midi, synthesizer

I've been working in a project where I need to manipulate each instrument in a MIDI file in java.
Then I decided to get each MIDI Event from each track from the Sequence and send it to a Receiver. After that the thread waits the time each tick lasts then do it again with the next tick. 
The problem is: the sound of the instruments gets very messed, as well as their order. 
I tried to execute each track alone too, but it's still messed!
The code:

```
    Sequence    sequence        = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File(source));
    Synthesizer synth           = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();

    //Gets a MidiMessage and send it to Synthesizer
    Receiver    rcv             = synth.getReceiver();

    //Contains all tracks and events from MIDI file
    Track[]     tracks          = sequence.getTracks();
    synth.open();

    //If there are tracks
    if(tracks != null)
    {
        //Verify the division type of the sequence (PPQ, SMPT)
        if(sequence.getDivisionType() == Sequence.PPQ)
        {
            int     ppq         = sequence.getResolution();
            //Do the math to get the time (in miliseconds) each tick takes 
            long    tickTime    = TicksToMiliseconds(BPM,ppq);
            //Returns the number of ticks from the longest track
            int     longestTrackTicks   = LongestTrackTicks(tracks);

            //Each iteration sends a new message to 'receiver'
            for(int tick = 0; tick < maiorTick ; tick++)
            {   
                //Iteration of each track
                for(int trackNumber = 0; trackNumber < tracks.length; trackNumber++)
                {
                    //If the number of ticks from a track isn't already finished
                    //continue
                    if(tick < tracks[trackNumber].size())
                    {
                        MidiEvent ev = tracks[trackNumber].get(tick);
                        rcv.send(ev.getMessage(),-1);
                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep(tickTime);
            }

        }
    }
    synth.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ntabee said, `Track.get(n)` returns the `n`th event in the track; to get events by time, you have to compare the events' times manually.

Furthermore, `Thread.sleep()` is not very precise and can wait for a longer time than desired.
These errors will add up.

---

To change MIDI messages in real time, tell the sequencer to play to your own `Receiver`, then do whatever you want to the events and pass them on to the 'real' `Receiver`.

Answer (score 0):

At least, your code looks like ringing on/off something at *every* `tickTime` msec. period.
`track.get(tick)` just returns the `tick`-th  event in the track, *not* the event(s) *at the moment* of `tick`.
If your goal is just playing a sound, Java provides a high level API for it, see e.g. http://www.jsresources.org/examples/midi_playback_and_recording.html

Comment: The problem is that I need to manipulate the instruments while the music is playing. That's why I didn't use the sequencer before.
The idea is to change the volume of some instruments while they are playing.
Furthermore, the track.get(tick) returns the MIDI Event.Java documentation says that MIDI Event has MIDI Message and this one contains all the information about sound at that tick.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the sequencer. I didn't know, but the "start" method runs in a new thread and while it's still running I can mute each instrument I want to, and that is exactly what I wanted.
Thanks for the answers!